How to auto stop sagemaker notebooks
I need a solution that can stop my notebook instance when it is idle or not in use
I was trying working with lifecycle configuration but when I add it to my instance, I am unable to start it
I added this code
#!/bin/bash
set -e

IDLE_TIME=300

echo "Fetching the autostop script"
wget -O autostop.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariokostelac/sagemaker-setup/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/autostop.py

echo "Starting the SageMaker autostop script in cron"
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/python3 $DIR/autostop.py --time ${IDLE_TIME} | tee -a /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/auto-stop-idle.log'") | crontab -

echo "Changing cloudwatch configuration"
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariokostelac/sagemaker-setup/master/scripts/publish-logs-to-cloudwatch/on-start.sh | sudo bash -s auto-stop-idle /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/auto-stop-idle.log

But still was unable to start the instance

Please note that the approach described below is specific to SageMaker Notebook instances only. If you are using SageMaker Studio notebooks, different Lifecycle configurations will be required.
For SageMaker Notebook instances, this GitHub repository offers various examples of Lifecycle configurations, including an auto-stop-idle script. This script will automatically shut down your instance if it remains idle for more than one hour.
To implement this, you will need to:

Create a Lifecycle configuration that incorporates the auto-stop-idle script
Attach this configuration to your instance while creating or editing a Notebook instance

If you should be using a custom VPC with your Notebook instance, please note that internet access is required for this particular script.
